# using sed replace string containing $ and ( and '

Tags: shell-script

As a part of a shell script, I want to replace

```
LIBTOOL='$(SHELL) $(top_builddir)/libtool'
```

with

```
LIBTOOL=./libtool
```

The source line number is 528. I try to using sed as follow

```
sed -e '528 s/LIBTOOL=\'\$(SHELL) \$(top_builddir)\/libtool'/LIBTOOL=.\/libtool/'**
```

but I received an error.

So any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you mind to include the error message with your question?

Answer (score 0):

You've got another unescaped single quote inside your expression (look at `\/libtool'/LIBTOOL`). So here is what works for me:

```
sed "528 s/LIBTOOL='\$(SHELL) \$(top_builddir)\/libtool'/LIBTOOL='.\/libtool'/" filename.ext
```

Note that I did **not** include the `-e` parameter, as that expects a filename to read its **expressions** from (and you provide the expression at the command line -- don't confuse this file with the file to be processed).